# How to use .filter to find the values between an array and a array in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello everyone I have two arrays that look like this:

```
  var arr=  [[1529539200,15.9099,16.15,15.888,16.0773,84805.7,1360522.8],[1529625600,16.0768,17.38,15.865,17.0727,3537945.2,58937516],[1529712000,17.0726,17.25,15.16,15.56,3363347.2,54172164]]
```

One is an array within an array (as you can see above)

And the other is like this:

```
var arr2= [ 1647475200, 1647561600, 1647648000, 1647734400, 1647820800, 1647907200, 1647993600, 1648080000, 1648166400, 1648252800]
```

What I want to do, is use the values from arr2 and see at which values they correspond to the numbers in arr[][0]

For example, arr[100][0] is 153817920. I want javascript to go to arr, and tell me at which point arr2=153817920.

I tried to use .filter but the result just gave out one value, wheras there should be 120 results as arr has a length of 120. Sorry if this is a little confusing, I am not 100% sure what is the correct word for this. I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
arr = [[1,1], [7,6], [3,9]];
arr2 = [1, 6, 4, 7];
index = arr.map(x => {
    return arr2.findIndex(y => x[0] == y);
})
console.log(index)
```

Comment: roughly this but this doesn't work,  I think because to access the value in arr I need to do arr[value][0], I think it needs to be ran through a loop to reach the result for arr as arr is an array and it has a bunch of arrays inside of it with a bunch of objects, with object [0] being the one I need to access. Thanks for the help

Comment: In my answer `x` indeed corresponds to an array within `arr`, so `x[0]` would be the first object you want to match against the number in `arr2`. Did you click on "Run code snippet" and verify that the result is not what you expected? If so, what would be the result you expect for this example?

Comment: The result here is good, however when I put int in with my code it didn't work. It says index is not defined   :(

Comment: `index` is just a dummy variable I used to refer to the resultant array, and the `console.log()` part is just to display that resultant array on the console (so that you can see it as snippet result). I don't think the `console.log` are necessary in actual code, though.

Comment: yes sorry my mistake, I fixed that and put it in, thank you so much! I was stuck on this and had no clue! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand you're trying to find the index of each element from arr in arr2. So please, try this:

```
const findEachValueOfArrFromArr2 = (arr, arr2) => {
const result = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const insideArray = arr[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < insideArray.length; j++) {
        const element = insideArray[j];
        const arr2Index = arr2.findIndex(e => e === element);
        // if arr[i][j] can not be found in arr2 the result will be -1 
        const resultObj = {
            row: i,
            col: j,
            indexAtArr2: arr2Index,
        }
        result.push(resultObj);
    }
}
return result
```

}